# JSF show icon without Button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to show the icons without buttons but it doesn't work. I get the following message: no Mime-Type was Found.

The two icons are default icons from Primefaces.

I use JSF 2.1 and primefaces 3.5

```
<h:graphicImage rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" name="ui-icon-mail-closed"/>
<h:graphicImage rendered="#{task.IS_SEEN}" name="ui-icon-mail-closed"/>
```

If I use buttons it would work or can I set that the button can not be pressed

```
<p:commandButton rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" icon="ui-icon-mail-closed" />
<p:commandButton rendered="#{task.IS_SEEN}" icon="ui-icon-mail-open" />
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want just a clickable image that trigger an action in the backing bean I suggest wrapping a graphic image in a `h:commandLink`.

```
<h:commandLink rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" value="" action="#{YourBean.myAction}">
    <h:graphicImage  value="your-image-here"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

If you want easy to use, nice, vectorial icons I suggest you to check Font Awesome http://fontawesome.io/icons/ as well.

To use Font Awesome just include the following line in your `<h:head>`:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
```

Then you can easily put the icons inside commandLinks in this simple way:

```
<h:commandLink rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" value="" action="#{YourBean.myAction}">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
</h:commandLink>
```

Comment: hi eldbuild who can i use this pics
<h:graphicImage   rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" class="fa fa-envelope" />

Comment: Use *styleClass* attribute for h tag: 
<h:graphicImage rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" styleClass="fa fa-envelope" />

Answer (score 10):

Also you need specify css class **ui-icon** like this:

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed" />
```

Answer (score 0):

those are in fact CSS classes that point to a sprite file, so technically they are not icons.

try using:

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-icon-mail-closed" rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" />
```

and if there's a need style it accordingly with padding.

Comment: it doesnt work i use it in a dataTable with colum , can this be a problem?

Comment: btw, try it with Font Awesome as elbuild suggested, it's really awesome!

Comment: but in fontawesome thier are no open mail pictures and is fontawesome free?